# React js in index.js file we are calling reactDOM render in that parentheses we call two parameter how its work

Tags: reactjs

I am new to development, learning react js.

*React.js* in `index.js` file we are calling `ReactDOM` render in that parentheses we call two parameter one is another page and one is  `document.getElementById('root')`

Eg:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: See: [ReactDOM: render()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render)

Comment: react-dom will render whatever is inside App, into that **root** element.. that root element is defined in `public/index.html`.. for testing/learning reason you can put different element in that html file and target different JSX to that.. and don't forget to inspect and checkout what's happening there..

Comment: It says where you want to render your component (eg <APP/>) on the DOM. usually its 'root'